# Large database update no error message

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an invoice generation process that is relatively large but not massive, it creates a batch of invoices and items and then updates a sql database everything has been working fine until now where the process just appears to stop part way through without showing any error messages or reason for the abrupt stop.

I'm completely stumped on my test environment I have increased execution time-out

```
<httpRuntime
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="3600" />
```

this appears to of helped but the server still does fails, without any errors its very difficult to point out the issue, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is saving data from UI, it would not make any sense to increase timeout of database, so issue seems to be related to only through your connection part, as by the data is saved, connection is lost and data is not completely saved.
Try using something like

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyReport", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 3660;
```

or

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add name="CommandTimeout" value="3600" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try but surely of the connection is lost then an error should be returned?